# Vertical-Alignment on top of the page not working

Tags: html, css

I am working with a wordpress-theme.
I want my headings on the pages aligned on top below the header. However it is not working.

´vertical-align:top´ is not working, nothing is happening: i have one page with a h1-text and h4-text, h4 is properly aligned in the center of the page, while i want h1 aligned at the top of the page. I know I need to adress the div in which h1 is placed.

```
.module_row_0 .module_column_0.tb_27_column.module_column > div.tb-column-inner, .module_row_0 .module_column_0.tb_27_column.module_column > .tb_holder {

  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 50px;

.headlines{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

and the respective html-part:

```
< div class="tb-column-inner">


< !-- module text -->
< div id="text-27-1-0-0" class="module module-text text-27-1-0-0 headlines repeat  " data-id="e154311">
<!--insert-->

    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
 < h1>Some Text</h1>
 < hr>
 < h1>&nbsp;</h1>        </div>
 < !-- /module text -->
```

...

I want the h1 aligned on top of the page, at the moment it is aligned in the center of the page like the h4.

Edit: The problem seems to be a flex-container, it basically looks like that:

```
< div> //row
  < div id="content_area"> // column with flex-container
    < div id="headlines"> headline 1 //should be at the top of the page but is centered
    < div> headline 4 //is centered and should stay like that
```

Is it possible without removing the flex-container? `align-self:flex-start;` did not work, making everything align at the top and align the h4-text did not work either.

Comment: Can you show the css of the parent element, too?

Comment: I added the part you asked for.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the padding?

Comment: removing the padding does not help

Comment: There's no overlapping styles on the same element?

Comment: I dont think there are some, at least I found none, but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: If you got an flex-container on an parent element, there's no way to use the vertical-align method (as far as I know). But you can use the method in the answer below. That should work the same.

Comment: It did not work. I am still working on it.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the part you're working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why `vertical-align: top;` isn't working for you, but you should be able to achieve the same result by setting `position` to `absolute` and `top` to `0%`. Be sure that the parent element has `position` set to `relative` or the child element can possibly exit its parent.

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```